# Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

Tags: solidity, metamask, javascript, json-rpc

function TriggerContract() {
        var account = getAccounts();
        var test = web3.eth.defaultAccount;

```
    console.log(account);
    var q = document.getElementById("Quantity").value;
    var u = toHex(document.getElementById("Unit").value);
    var m = toHex(document.getElementById("Material").value);
    var x = contractAddress.countMaterials(function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            console.log("Hey")
          }
        });
    console.log(x);
    contractAddress.setMaterial((test,q, u, m) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            console.log("YES")
          }
        });
    Reset();
  }
```

I get a "Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function" on the following line and have no idea why. The number of arguments should be correct. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
contractAddress.setMaterial((test,q, u, m)

function setMaterial(address _address, uint64 _weight, bytes16 _material, bytes16 _unit) public{
        materials[_address] = Material(_address, _weight, _unit, _material);

        materialAccounts.push(_address) -1;
        emit materialAdded(_materialID);
    }
```

Comment: The function below does work and this problem only seems to arise when I am trying to pass variables to my contract.                                                                 
 contractAddress.countMaterials(function(err, result) {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err)
     } else {
      console.log("Hey")
       <!--store.dispatch('pollWeb3', {q: q})-->
     }
   });

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is due to the absence of proper callback function. Please try below format and also try without result part( only err).

```
 functionname  (variables,function (error, result) {

              if (error) {
                  console.log(error)
              }
              else {
            console.log("yes")

              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    contractAddress.setMaterial((test,q, u, m) => {
```

To this:

```
    contractAddress.setMaterial(test,q, u, m).then(function(result, err) => {
```

Since I usually resolve promises with an `await` rather than a callback function, I'm not 100% sure about the prototype of `function(result, err)`. You should possibly use `function(err)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response however it didn't solve my problem

Comment: @MacdaraDay: If you're hoping to get some help here, then you should provide a little more than "it didn't solve my problem". I tried to endorse your attention to the incorrect syntax that you are using in `contractAddress.setMaterial((test,q, u, m) => {`, but your response doesn't refer to that in any way whatsoever. You should kind of understand that this is not a "please solve my problem" service, but rather a platform for solving problems in a manner of cooperation.

Comment: @goodvibrations Sorry I wasn't trying to complain or anything. I really appreciate you helping me I was just saying it to try and keep the thread open incase anyone else would have suggestions.

Comment: Adding the => causes an error. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>" and taking it out causes Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function